Is there an efficient algorithm to sample a connected DAG uniformly at random?
I would like to sample weakly connected  DAGs on $n$ labelled vertices uniformly at random. Is there an efficient (polynomial time) algorithm for this?
I could sample a graph with some probability $p$ of accepting each edge and then reject graphs that are not connected DAGs but that doesn't seem to work. It will for example be hugely inefficient.
Alternatively I could randomly permute the nodes, write them out from left to right, connect each one from its predecessor to make it connected and  randomly add edges from nodes  on the left to nodes on the right. This would make a connected DAG but it is not uniform. The difficulty is that some weakly connected DAGs can't be made this way.

Also, what does "that doesn't seem to work" mean?  See this previous Question.

@hardmath yes they are labelled, thank you I will add that to the question

What notion of connected are you using? The second algorithm would be uniform if we were sampling from the set of all DAGs such that for any two vertices $x, y$ there is either an $x \to y$ path or a $y \to x$ path. You could also relax the condition to weak connectivity (the underlying undirected graph is connected) - is that what you want?

@mishalavrov I intended weakly connected. I will edit the question, thank you. It’s great if my second method is uniform! I only need a proof of that now.

The second method is not uniform if we only want a weakly connected DAG, because then for example the $3$-vertex DAG with edges $1\to 3$ and $2 \to 3$ can never be chosen. It is uniform only on the set of graphs it is actually capable of producing.

@MishaLavrov It’s poorly specified as an algorithm as it doesn’t say how many edges should be added. This has to follow some random distribution.

I was assuming the straightforward way to make it uniform: decide whether to add each possible edge independently with probability $\frac12$. In that case, the only problem is that not all weakly connected graphs are generated.

@MishaLavrov Yes, I see the problem. I hope someone can solve it.

Probably just generate random uniform DAGs (https://hal.sorbonne-universite.fr/hal-03029381v2/document should do the trick) then reject disconnect DAGs

@caduk what would the rejection rate be using this method?

I don't kow but it should tend to 0 when $n$ grows.

The paper I cited allows control over the number of edges, but simpler methods that just sample uniform dags on $n$ vertices could be https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571065304003944 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.6590

There is a quite simple polynomial time algorithm for the related problem of sampling a tree from the more general $\lambda$-uniform distribution based on computing electrical flows (see Section 4.2 of https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/60990/Goemans_An%20O.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y). A faster method (near-linear time) was proposed by Anari et al. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.07220.

How does generating trees is more general than generating DAGs ?

It's not, but $\lambda$-uniform distributions are more general than uniform distributions.
